# Why is valet-share doesn't add slash to request like local valet do

Tags: laravel, nginx, ngrok, laravel-valet, valet

In local development using valet embedded images can be seen because the path to the storage is appended correctly with slash

https://restaurants.test/storage/app/public/34/ic_launcher.png

When I'd share the local site with Ngrok via valet share the embedded images to my site cannot be seen because the path to the storage is not appended correctly with slash

https://restaurants.teststorage/app/public/34/ic_launcher.png

*notice the restaurants.teststorage/app... part should have forward slash that separates it from the domain and slash

Answer (score 0):

It's because of APP_URL constant in the .env file, once you'd run valet share. It generates a link eg: http://testlive.ngrok.io/. In order for the redirection to go accordingly we need to update the APP_URL constant in the .env file to the link that is generated mentioned before.